# Repeated scale/zoom by small % creates cross/seam at center. How to mitigate?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, scale, zoom, python

I'm trying to process an image iteratively. I have an order of operations, specifically a series of effects. This process loops until I'm satisfied with the result. To showcase how the process ends up at the final result I'm making a little video, snapping a frame after each iteration.

Just one of effects is a slight zoom, say 5%. I'm running into an issue where after a few frames an obvious cross/seam begins to appear at the center of the zoom point. If I bump up the zoom to 30% the issue is nonexistent. I think there's some type of rounding error building up over time.

I'm doing this in python with OpenCV. But, I just tested Photoshop and it produced the same result. So, it seems this may be an issue someone else has run into. Yet, I cannot find any solutions in my research. I'm not certain this can be fully mitigated. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Note: This is an iterative process. I am running multiple effects on the image with each run of the process. The order of the operations matters. Therefore I need the previous frame to exist so I cannot simply re-reference the original image and scale to the appropriate size for any given frame.

Python example:

[image: python example]

Photoshop example:

[image: photoshop example]

Comment: Careful manual Clone Stamp and repair. There's no automated method here due to the intricacy of the artwork.

Comment: Now that you mention it I'm thinking about automatically inpainting the area every x num of frames.

Comment: Thing is, that *looks* like a possible wallpaper *pattern*. If it is, one could define the actual pattern tile and then use that. Your repeat isn't actually aligned in many areas, especially on the horizontal seam. This is just guessing without seems the full, original, untiled, art.

Comment: Is your image one flattened image or does it consist of multiple pieces? If it's the latter, flattening could work. (Although I don't fully understand what we are seeing here.)

Comment: Clearly, repeated resampling is the cause of the problem.  To be honest, perhaps you should use some video editing software instead to create a zoom effect. I think you could probably do it in AfterEffects or Blender, without the need to resample at all.  Note that video editing questions belong on Video Production Stack Exchange and are off-topic here.

Comment: The basic algorithm is unclear, but these look to be artifacts from e.g. blur on the composition edge. Many effects use pixels around each pixel and the edges of an image or tile will be lacking data because of the image boundary. If you can "overscan" each area and then crop it to tile size, this might help.

Comment: @WebandFlow - no I'm not a mod.  But you can flag your own question, and ask the mods to migrate it for you.

Comment: Obviously there is a buildup of sampling artifacts.  Can’t you always start from the original image, instead of scaling the previous frame.

Answer (score 0):

Some mitigations I've found:

- Rotate the image slightly as part of the "effects." Since the seams only appear after multiple passes of the scale effect this should prevent them from appearing by stopping any build-up of errors.